# Path not Found: The system cannot find the file C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, command-prompt, java-11

**java** & **java -version** commands are accessible from the **bin** folder of **JDK**, but I can not access them from desktop or anywhere else, but the programs are running successfully in **IDE**! What should I do?

**Inside the JDK bin folder:**

[image]

**From Desktop:**

[image]

Comment: Seems an earlier installation has left behind a symbolic link or such that refers to that no-longer-existing `java.exe`. Try command `where java` to see if that'll tell you how it's trying to resolve the `java` command. --- If you don't want to bother with that, just make sure the `...\jdk-11.0.6\bin` folder is **first** in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: @Andreas This is the command: C:\Users\RYANS>where java =>
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe =>
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe =>
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6\bin\java.exe

Comment: If you do a `dir` on those 3 files, what do you see? Please **edit** the question and show that `where java` output, as well as the new `dir` output. Show it as formatted text, not as an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JAVA_HOME` is used by third-party tools to find `java` (not by `java` itself). You **can** use that to set your `PATH`, which is what is searched.

```
set "PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"
```

Note that the quotes are correct in this command and moving (or removing) them will break it.

Comment: This is the command line used to update the PATH. If you want to modify system variables, then do that (and then reboot).

Answer (score 1):

"The system cannot find the file c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe"

There are steps to solve the problem which are

Step 1: GO TO `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`
and check for the `java.exe`, `javaw.exe` and `javaws.exe`
(You may found similar file name but with a different extension for e.g  .symlink)

Step 2: If you found the file name with different extension and size up to 0kb then delete it permanently.

Step 3: GO TO `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin`
and search for those three file names which are `java.exe`, `javaw.exe` and   `javaws.exe`

Step 4: Copy and Paste those three files in this location         `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`

Step 5: Close all your application related to java like your IDE or cmd
    & Restart PC and then try compile and run